# Accesing property of grandchild in VUE.js

Tags: vue.js

Using Vue, I want to ask you how to access 'someProperty' of componentC, which is son of componentB, which is son of componentA, within this grandfather componentA.

Next expresion doesn´t works:

```
this.$refs.componentB.componentC.someProperty
```

Comment: why it doesnt work ? it should be. can you access  `this.$refs.componentB` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ref to each child component, you would just do:

```js
this.$refs.componentB.$refs.componentC.someProperty
```